# VBA Offset and Paste

Tags: excel, vba

I have some VBA code that works fine, however I'm trying to improve my code by losing the select commands. I am learning that this is not best practice. The (old) code that works is below:

```
With Sheets("Data")
        RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To RowCount

        Range("B1").Offset(1, 0).Select

If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = 2 And ActiveCell.Value = sPeril Then

    ActiveSheet.Cells.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select

Selection.Copy
Sheets("DynamicCharts").Select
Sheets("DynamicCharts").Range("E" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Sheets("Data").Select

End If

next i

End With
```

The code switches between sheets copying and pasting using offset cells. Ive tried to change this with a WITH command and its debugging on the paste command.

```
With Sheets("Data")
    RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To RowCount

    Range("B1").Offset(1, 0).Select

    If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = 1 And ActiveCell.Value = sPeril Then

        ActiveSheet.Cells.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        With Sheets("DynamicCharts")
        .Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
        End With
        'Sheets("EDM Data").Select

    End If

next i

End With
```

Any help on this would be much appreicated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Remove the `.Selection` before `.PasteSpecial`. `Range` doesn't have a `Selection` member.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a shot instead - this completely removes the need for `Select`. We could also get rid of `Copy/Paste` as well, but I need to know what you're trying to bring over (maybe it's format specific?). Please include more of your code when asking a question (like what `sPeril` is, etc.):

```
Dim destrow As Long, lastcol As Long

With Sheets("Data")
    RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To RowCount

        If Range("B" & i).Offset(0, -1).Value = 2 And Range("B" & i).Value = sPeril Then

            destrow = Sheets("DynamicCharts").Cells(Sheets("DynamicCharts").Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
            lastcol = Sheets("Data").Cells(i, Sheets("Data").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            Sheets("Data").Range(Sheets("Data").Cells(i, 2), Sheets("Data").Cells(i, lastcol)).Copy
            Sheets("DynamicCharts").Range("E" & destrow + 1).PasteSpecial

        End If

    Next i

End With
```

Comment: Brilliant thanks very much for your comments. Apologies, its a pretty long code so didn't want to paste it all but you are right he sPeril is a little confusing its a variable from a drop down box.

Comment: `Range("B" & i).Offset(0, -1).Value` is `Range("A" & i).Value`

Comment: @Asger I'm well aware - I'm just leaving it as `Offset` because that's how they wrote it originally - maybe it's for their own sense of readability. Not my preference, but I'd rather not stray too far from the author's intent. If I had it my way, I'd trash all the `Range`s and replace them with `Cells(i, 2).Value`, etc. :)

Answer (score 1):

your code but with a simple fix just look at the comment. Note I set peril to 2 just so that i can make the code fall into that condition.

```
 Sub test2()
    With Sheets("sheet1")
        RowCount = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To RowCount

        Range("B1").Offset(1, 0).Select
        sPeril = 2
        If ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Value = 1 And ActiveCell.Value = sPeril Then

            ActiveSheet.Cells.Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            With Sheets("DynamicCharts")
            'remove selection on this line.
            .Range("A" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            End With
            'Sheets("EDM Data").Select

        End If

    Next i

    End With
    End Sub
```